# Missing class for indicator field value - EclipseLink exception

Tags: jpa, jaxb, eclipselink, unmarshalling

I am getting the follow error:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-43] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: Missing class for indicator field value [Component_Price_List] of type [class java.lang.String].
Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(com.celfocus.ufe.data.domains.productCatalog.PriceListItem --> [])
```

This is my ComponentPriceList.class

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Component_Price_List")
@Entity
@Table(name="PC_COMPONENT_PRICE_LIST")
public class ComponentPriceList
    extends PriceListItem
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}
```

And my PriceListItem.class is:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="PRICE_LIST_ITEM")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name="PC_PRICE_LIST_ITEM")
public abstract class PriceListItem
    extends LaunchEntity
{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

      ......
 }
```

I dont understand how this happens. What i can do to solve this problem? thanks